# Basic fitting question

Tags: real-analysis, functions, data-analysis

If the data (Y and X) is to be fit by a function of the type $f(x)=e^{ax}$ and I fit the Y vs. log(X) via f, and obtain the fit parameter $a$, is this $a$ parameter different than the desired one (in f(x)) even though i fit Y vs. log(X) instead of Y vs. X?

Or do I have to transform the parameter somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have $n$ data points $(x_i,y_i)$ and you want to fit accodring to the model $$y=e^{ax}$$ you must notice that the model is nonlinear with respect to the parameter. This means that nonlinear regression is required and then an initial estimate is required.

Writing $$\log(y)=a_1 x$$ makes the model linear and the resulting parameter is given by $$a_1=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \log(y_i) } { \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}$$ but this is just an estimate resulting from the minimization of $$SSQ_1=\sum_{i=1}^n (a_1x_i-\log(y_i))^2$$ while, since what is measured is $y_i$ and not $\log(y_i)$, what you want to minimize is $$SSQ_2=\sum_{i=1}^n (e^{a_2x_i}-y_i)^2$$ Except if the data do not contain any noise $a_2\neq a_1$.

For llustration purposes, let us consider the following data set 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 x_i & y_i \\
 1 & 2 \\
 2 & 3 \\
 3 & 4 \\
 4 & 7 \\
 5 & 10 \\
 6 & 16 \\
 7 & 25 \\
 8 & 39 \\
 9 & 61 \\
 10 & 96
\end{array}
\right)$$

The first step will lead to $a_1=0.460944$; using this estimate and stating the nonlinear regression, we should arrive to $a_2=0.456749$.

Comment: Dear Claude, thanks a lot for your answer. Would you be so kind as to add a few words on where the equations of $a_1, SSQ_{1,2}$ came from? I lack so much basic knowledge about fitting techniques, such as when to use log x or log y axes.... Never learnt how to reason about them. Any reference you d recommend would be much appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: $SSQ=$ **Sum** of **S**quares. Google for "exponential fit", "nonlinear regression". Come back if you need more.

Comment: I meant $SSQ=$ **S**um of **Sq**uares. index $1$ refers to the linearized model (first step) aand index $2$ refers to the true (nonlinear) model (second step).

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have meant log(Y) not log(X)

You are trying to find a function $f(x)$ in the form $e^{ax}$ such that $f(X)\approx Y$.  Instead, you found a function $g(x)$ such that $g(\log(X))\approx Y$, i.e. $g(\log(X))\approx f(X)=e^{aX}\implies \frac{\log(g(\log(x)))}{x}=a.$

If you did in fact mean log(Y) instead of log(X), you found a function $g(x)$ such that $g(X)\approx \log(Y)$, i.e. $e^{g(X)}\approx Y \approx f(X) = e^{aX}\implies g(x)=a\cdot x$ (the same $a$).

Comment: What do you mean by "this parameter a"? Are you saying that you were able to find an $a$ such that $y\approx e^{a\cdot \log(x)}$?  If so, then see that this simplifies to $y\approx x^a$

Comment: To clarify, if that is the case then your data is NOT fit by the exponential model, it is fit by the power model.  Whatever $a$ you found works for Y vs log(X) in the exponential equation is the power of x for your data.

Comment: Oh I see! Starting to understand. If i may ask another question: what if f(x) used in this case was not $e^{ax}$ but instead was $e^{ax^d}$, that is, a power of x different than 1. Then if the same scenario applies (Y vs log(x) fits), what does $e^{a log(x)^d}$ simplify to?

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing nice.  $x^{a\log(x)^{d-1}}$